# `Async` resolved with `then` but still I get undefined value

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Here is my code, I am trying to print the value in `GCPanel` react component as you can see, from where the chain of call starts.

```
import { ofetch } from 'ofetch'

export function parseBardResponse(resp: string) {  
  const text = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(resp.split('\n')[3])[0][2])[0][0] as string
  return { text}
}

const GCPanel:  = ({ chats }) => {
  const onUserSendMessage = useCallback(
    (input: string, botId?: BotId) => {
      const chat = chats.find((c) => c.botId === botId)
      let ret = chat?.sendMessage(input);          // ------------------> First called from here
      ret?.then((value) => {
        console.log("GCPanel ret:", value);  // <-------------But Here I get undefined value
      });
    },
    [chats],
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{chats.map((chat) => (
          <ConversationPanel onUserSendMessage={onUserSendMessage}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      <ChatMessageInput
        onSubmit={onUserSendMessage}/>
    </div>
  )
}


export abstract class AbstractBot {
  async sendMessage(params) {
    return await this.doSendMessage(params)   // --------------------> then relay called from here
  }
  abstract doSendMessage(params): Promise<void>
}

class DummyBot extends AbstractBot {
  async doSendMessage(_params) { // dummy
  }
}

export abstract class AsyncAbstractBot extends AbstractBot {
  #bot: AbstractBot

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.#bot = new DummyBot()
    this.initializeBot().then((bot) => {
      this.#bot = bot
    })
  }
  abstract initializeBot(): Promise<AbstractBot>

  doSendMessage(params) {
    return this.#bot.doSendMessage(params)
  }

  get name() {
    return this.#bot.name
  }
}


export class BBot extends AbstractBot {
  async doSendMessage(params) {
    const resp = await ofetch(
      'https://some_url',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: "somebody",
        parseResponse: (txt) => txt,
      },
    )
    const { text } = parseBardResponse(resp)
    console.log(text);//<-----------------------------------------Here I get valid text value
    params.onEvent({
      type: 'UPDATE_ANSWER',
      data: { text },
    })
    params.onEvent({ type: 'DONE' })
    return text; // <----------------- I want to return from here
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `chat` is defined?

Comment: @code yes it is defined.

Comment: You `sendMessage` via the `DummyBot`. and DummyBots `doSendMessage` returns a `Promise<void>` that's why `value` is `undefined`

Comment: @Thomas I see . I was under the impression `.then((value) => {});` is supposed to resolve that too. can you suggest the fix.

Comment: No, because `let ret = chat?.sendMessage(input);` is called before `this.#bot = bot` has happenned. 
I can suggest a patch, I don't know enough about what you're doing for a solution/fix. Instead of `#bot` store `#botPromise = this.initializeBot()` and when you forward calls, do it like this: `async doSendMessage(params) { const bot = await this.#botPromise; return bot.doSendMessage(params) }`

Comment: @Thomas well then every function of class `AsyncAbstractBot` has to be async, that complicates further. I need something simpler. Actually I don't need everything to be async, some of the things can be blocking.

Comment: "well then every function of class AsyncAbstractBot has to be async" well, that's the problem when every method of AsyncAbstractBot depends on `this.#bot` but they have no clue (besides the Promise) when or if ever this object is available. From their perspective, (the correct, not the Dummy) `this.#bot` will at some unknown point just magically exist.

Comment: @Thomas I mean `initializeBot()` can be blocking and `doSendMessage()` needs to be async. Let me explain my scenario, I have two bots . both can be initialised sequentially in blocking calls one after another, only each of their `doSendMessage` needs to be parallel and hence `async`